# Model for a thin metal/semiconductor junction?

Tags: resource-recommendations, semiconductor-physics

Are there any books or articles that describe models for transport in a metal/semiconductor junction where the thickness of the semiconductor is less than the thickness of the depletion/accumulation layer?